# You do not have permission to access this page - Contribution Page - WordPress Install

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, contributions, contribution-page

WP Version 5.8.2
CiviCRM Version 5.44.0

When trying to make a contribution when not logged in or in a private browser I get the following error sometimes on page load but more often after pressing the contribute button.

[image]

Using administer - users and permissions - permissions, I have set the following for the Anonymous User

CiviCRM: access uploaded files 
CiviCRM: profile create
CiviCRM: profile edit
CiviCRM: profile view
CiviCRM: access all custom data
CiviEvent: register for events
CiviEvent: view event info
CiviContribute: make online contributions
CiviMail: access CiviMail subscribe/unsubscribe pages
CiviCampaign: sign CiviCRM Petition
CiviVolunteer: register to volunteer

I also receive an email with the following info

```
***ERROR***
```

message:            You do not have permission to access this page.
code:
exception:          CRM_Core_Exception Object
(
[errorData:CRM_Core_Exception:private] => Array
(
[error_code] => 0
)

```
[cause:protected] => 
[_trace:PEAR_Exception:private] => 
[message:protected] => You do not have permission to access this page.
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 0
[file:protected] => /public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php
[line:protected] => 605
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => /public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php
                [line] => 60
                [function] => permissionDenied
                [class] => CRM_Utils_System_WordPress
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [file] => /public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php
                [line] => 233
                [function] => __callStatic
                [class] => CRM_Utils_System
                [type] => ::
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => permissionDenied
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [file] => /public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php
                [line] => 69
                [function] => runItem
                [class] => CRM_Core_Invoke
                [type] => ::
                [args] => Array
```

I have also disabled all WP plugin except for CiviCRM and still get the error, any help / advise appreciated thanks in advance.

Cheers

Stuart

Update
[Github Debug Info](https://github.com/JENetworkLtd/CIVICRM-Errors/blob/main/Debug)

Answer (score 2):

Juggy69 Welcome to CiviCRM SE. Since you are using stripe as payment gateway for taking payment can you please check if Anonymous and Authenticated users have `CiviCRM: access Ajax API` permission, if not try assigning those permission to both anonymous and authenticated user role?

Comment: Hi Pradeep, I have had the donations working before and had a permission issue with 5.42.0 and sorted that, so I have enabled Ajax API to all users and as soon as I load the contribution page I get the same screen as the image above?

Comment: I have also updated the main question with GitHub link to see debug log errors

Comment: Sorry the link is broken

Comment: Sorry edited the visibility of the repository

Answer (score 2):

So after messing with the WordPress Plugin User Role Editor and going through the Access permission controls again it now looks to be working with the following in Access Permissions

CiviCRM: access uploaded files
CiviCRM: profile create 
CiviCRM: profile edit 
CiviCRM: profile view
CiviCRM: access all custom data
CiviCRM: access AJAX API
CiviEvent: register for events
CiviEvent: view event info
CiviContribute: make online contributions
CiviMail: access CiviMail subscribe/unsubscribe pages
CiviCampaign: sign CiviCRM Petition
CiviVolunteer: register to volunteer

In the [image]User role editor image below