# Contribution - Config Error

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, contributions, payment-processor

When trying to make a contribution end users are getting the following error Configuration error - unable to process paymentIntent

Using CiviCRM 5.44.0, Stripe Payment Processor Extn Version 6.6.3

It was working on 10/12 from 12pm as I tested several times, and also around 2pm a 3rd party made a contribution, then literally the next day it has stopped working and I have changed nothing.

Setup the Payment Processors correctly as far as I can tell
[Payment Processors](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/payment-processors/)
[Payment Processors : Comparison](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/payment-processors/#comparison)

And also found this
[CivicRM payment Issues](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/issues/326)

```
Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method InvalidArgumentException::getRequestId() in 
/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/api/v3/StripePaymentintent.php:229\nStack trace:\n#0
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_stripe_paymentintent_process(Array)\n#1
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(149): Civi\\API\\Provider\\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke(Array)\n#2
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(81): Civi\\API\\Kernel->runRequest(Array)\n#3
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(22): Civi\\API\\Kernel->runSafe
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you make sure you have CiviCRM ajax api permission set for anonymous and authenticated user?

CiviCRM >> Administer >> Users and Permissions >> Permissions (Access Control) >> WordPress Access Control

Comment: Hi Predeep, that was already sorted in the previous post about You don not have access to the page ;-)

Comment: Ok so this looks like a permission issue again, if I use a "Private" browser I get the PaymentIntent failure message, if am logged in then the transaction is processed with the correct output message.

Comment: That means the anonymous user dont have CiviCRM ajax api permission permission

Comment: please see this post [link](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/40865/you-do-not-have-permission-to-access-this-page-contribution-page-wordpress-i)

Comment: can you check under /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Faccess%2Fwp-permissions&reset=1

Comment: I have that enabled, how do you attach and image via the comments rather than an answer?

Comment: What is your api version in stripe?

Comment: Do I find that in the Stripe Payment Processor extn or in Stripe itself?

Comment: API Version apparently https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2020-08-27

Comment: Was this until yesterday as changed for testing https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2019-12-03

Comment: Update to this when running the following at the end of the domain /?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fajax%2Frest 

{"IP":"IP Address ","level":"security","referer":null,"reason":"CSRF suspected","is_error":1,"error_message":"SECURITY ALERT: Ajax requests can only be issued by javascript clients, eg. CRM.api3()."}

This is also in a private browser